# Using a single certificate based on aliases from Java Key Store

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, jks

I have a keystore which has multiple keys and certificates added to it
I want to used a certificate based on the aliases from the key store and use it for SSL
I tried to set the following System properties but nothing helped

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyAlias", "abcd");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreAlias", "abcd");
```

It always uses the first certificate from the keystore instead of matching the key aliases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the [Customization section of the JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization) (or the entire guide), there's no `javax.net.ssl.keyAlias` or `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreAlias` property.

It's up to the application to have a way to select which certificate it wants, using its alias name, but it has to load it explicitly itself. Some frameworks use their own properties or configuration options.

Comment: True, I also didn't find such flag in the Refernce Guide; then I will go ahead with putting one certificate in each store. I read here https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1527095 that this flag was added in Java 6

Comment: I'm not sure that that link says anything about this alias property to be actually responsible for the different behaviour. All of this really depends on what is using your keystores, but you make no mention of anything in your question.

Comment: @ChatC There is nothing in that thread, to which I contributed, that says anything stronger than 'perhaps it is a new feature'. It isn't. There is no such property.