# javax.net.ssl.keyStoreAlias not work using keystoretype "Windows-MY"

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

I have a problem in connection of WebService using Certificates of Respository of Windows.

The problems is Windows get always the first certificate on repository ignoring the property keystoreAlias. I'd like now wath is wrong?

I have 3 certificates on repository and i want to use the third certificate, but the windows always select the first.

```
 ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
                try {
                    ks.load(null, configNFSe.getSenhaCertificadoDigital().toCharArray());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Exception("Senha do Certificado Digital esta incorreta ou Certificado inválido.");
                }



                Enumeration<String> aliasEnum = ks.aliases();
                while (aliasEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String alias = aliasEnum.nextElement();
                    if (ks.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
                        String certificado = alias;


                        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);

                        if (certificate.getSubjectDN().toString().equals(configNFSe.getAliasCertificado()) || alias.equals(configNFSe.getAliasCertificado())) {

                            keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(configNFSe.getSenhaCertificadoDigital().toCharArray()));

                            atualizarSenhaAliasCertificado(certificate);
                            Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
                            System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
                            System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
                            System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
                            System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");

                            System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
                            System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword");
                            System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
                            System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreAlias");

                            System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");

                            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreProvider", "SunMSCAPI");
                            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "Windows-MY" );
                            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "cert_jf_p.jks");
                            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "passwordCertificate");
                            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreAlias", alias);

                            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
                            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","cert_jf_p.jks");
                            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
```

This hasn't been needed since 2002.

```
System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreAlias");
```

I don't see the point of clearing properties you're about to set, but there is [no such property defined in JSSE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CustomizingStores).

```
 System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
```

This hasn't been needed since 2002.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreAlias", alias);
```

There is [no such property defined in JSSE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CustomizingStores).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12817002/207421) for confirmation.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how i say for my application the certificate of windows to use, do you can help me? There is any way to do?