# How to use a particular key in key-store for configuring SSL in Kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I have 3 different keys in my key-store but I want to use only one of that to configure ssl in Kafka. Is it possible by using aliases, if is it is what is the property that I should use.

I am using spring boot kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Spring delegates to the `kafka-clients` library.

I have looked at its `SslFactory` class and I don't see a mechanism to select which key(s) to use.

According to [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817002/using-a-single-certificate-based-on-aliases-from-java-key-store), that's where I would expect the code to be.

> It's up to the application to have a way to select which certificate it wants, using its alias name, but it has to load it explicitly itself.

And the `SslFactory` doesn't appear to be pluggable.

**EDIT**

Actually I think the code would be in `SslEngineBuilder` but there is nothing there either.